# SAS trigger error in SAS program executed from SAS-EG

Tags: sas

I need to get SAS to trigger an error if a certain condition is not meet 
i have tried to use abort return n, abort abend etc.. but they all seems to 
to disconnect the entire session where i only want to get an error like 
with syntax etc.

It is a sas propgram only to be run from SAS-EG in interactive mode with prompts

my code:

```
DATA _NULL_;
IF prxmatch("/^TBDLZL\d{4}_[A-Z]/",&tablename_in) eq 0 then do;
    put "error table name &tablename_in does not match";
    ABORT RETURN 15; 
END;

RUN;
```

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use:

```
put 'ERROR:' '/*customize error text here*/';
```

If you want to stop executing data step you can use `stop` statement, for example:

```
DATA _NULL_;
   IF prxmatch("/^TBDLZL\d{4}_[A-Z]/",&tablename_in) eq 0 then do;
       put 'ERROR:' "table name &tablename_in" does not match;
       stop; 
   END;
RUN;
```

If you have macros and you want to get ERROR message at macro execute step you can use `%put`:

```
%put ERROR: /*customize error text here*/;
```

Thanks [@Tom](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

> Note the "trick" of breaking the word ERROR(`put ‘ERR’ ‘OR:’...`)into two parts is only needed if you are using a dumb search of your logs for errors. Normal SAS error messages in the log always appear at the beginning of the line. SAS/Studio for example does not falsely mark the program lines that contain ERROR as if they were actual errors.

Thanks @MichaelKersten

> Another neat trick for multi-line NOTEs, WARNINGS and ERRORS is to
>   replace the ":" with a "-" for the second and consecutive lines.
>   Example:
>
> ```
> %put WARNING: first line of warning; 
> %put WARNING- second line of warning;
> ```

Comment: Shouldn't you have used PUT vs %PUT?

Comment: Note the "trick" of breaking the word ERROR into two parts is only needed if you are using a dumb search of your logs for errors.  Normal SAS error messages in the log always appear at the beginning of the line.  SAS/Studio for example does not falsely mark the program lines that contain ERROR as if they were actual errors.

Comment: @Tom Personally I use that trick for doing a `CTRL-F` style find to search through the log for the first occurrence of `ERROR:`.  Considering I'm either in the Base SAS IDE or SAS Studio, I never have the option to include a newline as part of the search expression.

Comment: Consider me triggered ;), I prefer simple search.

Comment: Another neat trick for multi-line NOTEs, WARNINGS and ERRORS is to replace the ":" with a "-" for the second and consecutive lines.
Example:
`%put WARNING: first line of warning;`
`%put WARNING- second line of warning;`

Answer (score 5):

Use the `ABORT CANCEL` statement.  The data step will stop running and the following steps in the submitted code will not be processed.

For example:

```
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class;
  if name = "John" then do;
    put 'ERR' 'OR: My error message';
    abort cancel;
  end;
run;

* This step is not done due to earlier ABORT CANCEL;
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class;
  where name like 'J%';
run;
```

From Help:

> **CANCEL** 
>   causes the execution of the submitted statements to be canceled.
>   Actions depend on the method of operation.
>
> - batch mode and noninteractive mode
>
>   - terminates the entire SAS program and SAS system.
>   - writes an error message to the SAS log.
> - windowing environment and interactive line mode
>
>   - clears only the current submitted program.
>   - does not affect other subsequent submitted programs.
>   - writes an error to the SAS log.
> - workspace server and stored process server
>
>   - clears only the currently submitted program.
>   - does not affect other subsequent submit calls.
>   - writes an error message to the SAS log.
> - SAS IntrNet application server
>
>   - creates a separate execution for each request and submits the
>       request code. A CANCEL argument in the request code clears the current
>       submitted code but does not terminate the execution or the SAS session.

Comment: If we want to abort only the first step but continu to run the following steps, what we can use instead of "abort cancel". And is it the same command in a macro ? thank you...

Comment: In macro use `%ABORT CANCEL` to halt all submitted code. Use `%return` to exit macro at a point of your choosing.  In `DATA` step the `STOP` statement will halt the step at the point of your choosing.  NOTE: If an error occurs during a submitted block of code the session or submit may go into `SYNTAXCHECK` or `DMSSYNCHK` mode, or the session can terminate (based on option `ERRORABEND`) -- further depending on batch or interactive session.  Read the docs for full understanding.